# NHibernate - how get item with particular column value

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Using `NHibernate`, I need to retrieve a row that matches particular criteria (like, **ProjectId==1245**).

How I could do that, providing that I got ISession object and is able to query? 
How I do that if many rows are matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an object mapped called Project and it looks like this id is unique then you could use:

```
var firstProjectMatching = (from p in session.Query<Project>() 
                               where p.Id == 1245
                               select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you think there might be many then you could count them

```
   var projectCount = (from p in session.Query<Project>() 
                                   where p.Id == 1245
                                   select p.Id).ToList().Count;
```

and if you wanted them all with all their data

```
var projects = (from p in session.Query<Project>() 
                                       where p.Id == 1245
                                       select p).ToList();
```

and you can `.Count` this list

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that ProjectId is the primary identifier (mapped with identity in your NH mapping), then you should use

```
var entity = session.Get (1245);
```

The Get and Load methods of ISession are optimized to retrieve entities via primary key.

When you want to retrieve an entity using a property that is not the primary key, you should use [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html), [ICriteria](http://docs.huihoo.com/hibernate/nhibernate-reference-1.2.0/querycriteria.html) or [QueryOver](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx)